# create variable to contain a number in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

In my function I'd create a variable that will contain simply one number. How do I initialize it?I have to initialize it to 0 value or I can initialize it simply putting in function `var;`

Comment: If your variable is named `X`. Just add `X=0;` at the beginning of your function (after the line `function...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, variables are initialized dynamically. There is no C++ or Java equivalent of memory allocation versus initialization.

For example:

C code:

```
 int x; // Allocate memory on the stack for integer.
 x = 5; // Assign the value 5
```

Matlab code:

```
 x = 5;  %# Allocate memory and assign the value 5
```

You **can't** break this in two parts in the following way:

```
 x; %# SYNTAX ERROR! x is not defined yet.
 x = 5;
```

---

Also, I am not sure whether you meant that `var` is some kind of a keyword, but in case you think it is - you're mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

```
var = 0;
```

Just set it to the number. No initialization needed. Matlab variables are fully dynamic.

You can also do something like

```
global myvar;
```

and this will  create a variable equal the the empty list []

You can overwrite variables too without worrying about types.

```
myvar %equal to []
myvar = 1543 % equal to 1543
myvar = 'a string hello' %Now myvar is a string
myvar = {item1, item2, item3} % now myvar is a cell array containing 3 items.
```

Comment: but the variable will take value during the execution and not at the beginning.so initially I have to put it to zero?

Comment: Just a small point, if your first line of code is really the first and you have not defined `myvar`, it will throw an error. Other than that, a good answer